# error: cannot call member function 'sf::Time sf::Clock::getElapsedTime() const' without object

Tags: c++, sfml

```
 void update(bool moright, bool moleft)
    {
        Clock Clock();
        if (moright == true){
            xvel = 5;
            }
        if (moleft == true){
            xvel = -5;
        }
        if (!(moright || moleft)){
            xvel = 0;
        }
        sf::Time t1 = seconds(0.1f);
        Time time1 = Clock::getElapsedTime() // error 1 here
        while (time1 << 0.16666666);
            time1 = clock::getElapsedTime(); // error 2 here
    }
```

returns: error: cannot call member function 'sf::Time sf::Clock::getElapsedTime() const' without object
and: error: 'clock' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
New to sfml and c++ so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use identical identifier for type _and_ name. 2. Changing this to `Clock clock();` may raise another issue: It is compiled as function declaration (instead of a default construction). So, it had to be `Clock clock;`  or `Clock clock{};`.

Comment: `Clock` and `Clock` and `clock`? That's a lot of "clocks" that makes it very hard to understand your code.

Comment: `sf::Clock::getElapsedTime()` is not a static function (according to [sf::Clock Class Reference](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php)). So, it should be called `clock.getElapsedTime();` (assuming `clock` is declared with `sf::Clock clock;` before). (And that's the actual reason for the error in your title.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Sorry to bother you, but changing it to:                                                    void update(bool moright, bool moleft)
    {
        Clock clock;
        sf::Time t1 = seconds(0.1f);
        Time time1 = clock.getElapsedTime();
        while (time1 < 0.16666666);
            time1 = clock::getElapsedTime();
    }                                                                                                                                            returns:    error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'sf::Time' and 'double')

Comment: Isn't the error clear? There is no `<` operator to compare object `time1` of type `sf::Time` with `0.166` which is a `double` constant. You have to convert one of them to get two expressions for which the `<` operator is available. Why don't you look into doc. of [sf::Time](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Time.php) for what it does provide? (Spoiler: I did, and I found something.) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clock Clock();
```

Let's just call your `sf::Clock` instance something that's differ from that class name, like `clock`. While it is not an error, it can be confusing.

```
Clock clock();
```

Also, notice that, this line can be ambiguous for the compiler, because it looks like a function prototype named `clock`, that takes no argument and returns an `sf::Clock` instance. Just remove the parantheses.

```
Clock clock;
```

---

```
sf::Time t1 = seconds(0.1f);
```

`t1` is not used in this function, can be deleted.

---

```
Time time1 = Clock::getElapsedTime()
```

This line is trying to call the **static function** `getElapsedTime`. The `sf::Clock` class doesn't have a static function named like that, just a **member function**. This call, and the one after the `while` loop are the cause of the compiler errors that you described.

```
Time time1 = Clock.getElapsedTime()
```

It is still not good. Notice the missing `;` at the end of the line.

```
Time time1 = Clock.getElapsedTime();
```

---

```
while (time1 << 0.16666666);
```

You used the operator `<<` here, that is the "bitwise left shift" operator. What you meant is the "less than" operator (`<`), but because you want to check if a specific amount of time is elapsed, you should use the "greater than" operator (`>`).

```
while (time1 > 0.16666666);
```

But that still wouldn't work, because `time1` is an `sf::Time` instant, and you cannot compare an `sf::Time` with a float. You have to call the [`asSeconds`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Time.php#aa3df2f992d0b0041b4eb02258d43f0e3) member of `time1`, that returns the elapsed time in seconds as a float.

```
while (time1.asSeconds() > 0.16666666);
```

One more important thing, you put a `;` at the end of the line, that means that the `while` loop has an empty body, and it will run forever (if `time1` is not greater than `0.16666666`). You have to delete the semicolon at the end, and your next line will become the body if the loop.

```
while (time1.asSeconds() > 0.16666666)
```

---

```
time1 = clock::getElapsedTime();
```

This line replaces the value of `time1` with the result of `getElapsedTime`. What you meant is to **add** the elapsed time to `time1`, you can achieve that by replacing `=` with `+=`.

```
time1 += Clock::getElapsedTime();
```

The line above still contains two more errors. As before, `sf::Clock` doesn't have a static function called `getElapsedTime`, plus `clock` does not exists in your code (just `Clock` with a capital `C`).

```
time1 += Clock.getElapsedTime();
```

I assume here, that you wanted to wait for a specific amount of time to pass, with this `while` loop. For that purpose you could use the [`sf::sleep`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/group__system.php#gab8c0d1f966b4e5110fd370b662d8c11b) function.

```
sf::sleep(sf::seconds(0.16666666f));
```